# Importing databases which contain cross schema views

Tags: mysql

I am dealing with a project which uses cross-schema views heavily.
The problem I am looking to solve is importing these schemas in simple manner, without errors.

I'll explain this further:
Let's say the schemas are A and B. In schema A there is a view which points to schema B and the other way around. 
When importing the A mysqldump file, it fails mid-way, since the view points to schema B which doesn't exist yet. Same thing happens when importing the B schema first.

I couldn't find a way to disable support for view validation, or something to that extent.
Does anyone has an idea how to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using some advanced DB client, as Navicat, or MicroOLAP for MySQL.